# How to insert a new key with value in dictionary 

Tags: iphone, key, nsmutabledictionary

I want to insert a key with a corresponding value in an existing dictionary...

I am able to set values for existing keys in the dictionary, but I am not able to add a new key value...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use NSMutableDictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *yourMutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[yourMutableDictionary setObject:@"Value" forKey:@"your key"];
```

**Update for Swift:**

The following is the exact swift replica for the code mentioned above

```
var yourMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
yourMutableDictionary.setObject("Value", forKey: "Key")
```

But i would suggest you to go with Swift Dictionary way.

```
var yourMutableDictionary = [String: AnyObject]() //Open close bracket represents initialization

//The reason for AnyObject is a dictionary's value can be String or
//Array or Dictionary so it is generically written as AnyObject

yourMutableDictionary["Key"] = "Value"
```

Comment: how to know whether the given key is existed or not in dictionary

Comment: [yourMutableDictionary allKeys];   This will return an array of all keys in that dictionary and compare that with your given key and know it

Comment: By the way, if you _have_ to convert back to a NSDictionary you can by casting it like `yourNSDictionary = yourMutableDictionary as NSDictionary`.

Comment: and how to add any object class as value and int as key?

Answer (score 2):

NSDictionnary is immutable. Use NSMuteableDictiory instead.

[adding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Objects: `setObject:forKey:`

Testing if key is present:

```
[[aDict allKeys] containsObject:@"key"];
```

Comment: for nsmutable dictionary how to insert new key value

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

By using this method we can add the new value to NSMutableDictionary

```
[dict setObject:@"Value" forKey:@"Key"];
```

To know wheather the key exist in dictionary

```
[[dict allKeys] containsObject:@"key"];
```

Comment: cv::Mat as value and int as key how to add it to NSMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am getting the content from json in the format of dictionary and from that i am adding the content into some other dictionary

```
  //here contract is my json dictionary 
  NSArray *projectDBList =[contract allKeys];//listing all the keys in dict 

  NSMutableDictionary *projectsList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

  [projectDBList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

  [projectsList setObject:[contract objectForKey:obj] forKey:obj];

  }];
```