# How to store { "Abc" :"Xyz" } in NSDictionary in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios8.3

How to store the given below into NSDictionary

{

"Test":"Example"

}

Comment: NSmutableDictionary *info = [NsmutableDictionary allo]init]; [info setObject:passValue forKey:passKeyValue];  // like [info setObject:@"Example" forKey:@"Test"];

Comment: `NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Test":@"Example"};` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a new key with value in dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285875/how-to-insert-a-new-key-with-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You can add value for key by using this

```
NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test",@"Example", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add value for key by using 'initWithObjects:(objects) forKeys:'

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"Example",@"Example2"] forKeys:@[@"Test",@"Test2"]];
NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
//{
//    Test = Example;
//    Test2 = Example2;
//}
```

Or you can use NSMutableDictionary :

```
 NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[mutableDictionary setObject:@"Example" forKey:@"Test"];
[mutableDictionary setObject:@"Example2" forKey:@"Test2"];
NSLog(@"%@",mutableDictionary);
//{
//    Test = Example;
//    Test2 = Example2;
//}
```

Same output for these.  [Also you should take a look](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/)